# Can i count "hours" in a row with SUM, but show Names/Characters in the cell?

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I would like to let Google Sheets count "hours" in a row together, BUT we use "Characters" instead of Numbers when we update the Document.

Can we do a secondary Table and calculate everything together and then output the total number in the original table?

I've made a picture for a easier understanding:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/IxXjIWL.png]

Comment: Yes your idea is good. That's possible. Either build a virtual table in an array formula or some `VLOOKUP` stuff.

Comment: how did you get **55** ??

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IFNA(HLOOKUP(A1:Q1; 
 {{"F" ; 8,5 }\ 
  {"U" ; 7,7 }\ 
  {"D" ; 2   }\ 
  {"N1"; 11,3}}; 2; 0))))
```

[image]

---

for multiple rows use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IFNA(HLOOKUP(A1:Q3; 
 {{"F" ; 8,5 }\ 
  {"U" ; 7,7 }\ 
  {"D" ; 2   }\ 
  {"N1"; 11,3}}; 2; 0))*1; ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COLUMNS(A1:Q)))^0))
```

[image]

Comment: fixed, see your sheet

Comment: +1 man! what did you changed so it works? :) When i copy the Formula in my original, its still not working

Comment: depend on your language settings. if your spreadsheet is non-english use formulas from answer if your spreadsheet is English use formulas from pictures in the answer. note that English dot `.` should be non-english comma `,` and English comma `,` should be non-english ` \ ` in curly array brackets `{}` but semicolon `;` outside curly brackets

Comment: can you share your original sheet?